# How will I get the per-unit parameters when the data from the short-circuit test are shady?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, test, ratings

> Data from short-circuit and open-circuit tests of a 60-Hz, 100-kVA, 4600–230-V transformer are:
>
> V<sub>OC</sub> = 230 V
>   I<sub>OC</sub> = 14 A
>   P<sub>OC</sub> = 60 W
>
> V<sub>SC</sub> = 172.3 V
>   I<sub>SC</sub> = 20.2 A
>   P<sub>SC</sub> = 1046 W
>
> Get (a) the magnetizing reactance referred to the high side and (b) the per-unit parameters.

I<sub>SC</sub> ≠ I<sub>rated</sub>, so how will I solve for (b)?

The problem is from the book with ISBN 0130612103.

Comment: Which winding was being used for the first test (open circuit)?

Comment: The low-voltage side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to show you how to calculate magnetization inductance: -

Magnetization reactance is calculated from the open circuit tests. You are using the secondary as the means for testing mag inductance and, with 230V applied, the transformer is taking 14A at 60 watts. The 14A is mainly magnetization current with a little bit producing the 60 watts in real power dissipation.

Real power (eddy current and hysterisis losses) produce a current of: -

\$\dfrac{60W}{230V}\$ = 0.26A

By pythagorous, the mag current is \$\sqrt{14^2 - 0.26^2}\$ = 13.997A.

Therefore mag inductive reactance is 230V/13.997A = 16.43 ohms or, at 60Hz an inductance of 2.61 henries.